# Programmatically cloning Octopus Deploy Process steps and modifyng the cloned steps

Tags: octopus-deploy

We are developing a Pipeline for which we have to add over 100 steps and modify two things for each step:  Step Name and PackageID.
Rather than going through the pain of doing this via the UI, we’d like to do this programmatically.

Below is some C# I’ve sketched out for this (I’m a C# developer with extremely limited PowerShell skills, that’s why I did this in C#).
The lines above the comment “From here on is where I'm fuzzy” are working code, but the lines below the comment are just pseudocode.

Can someone explain to me how to write the lines below the comment (or, the PowerShell equivalent)?
I wasn’t able to find API calls for this.

Thanks

```
    namespace ODClientExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> ListOfWindowsServices = new List<string>();
            ListOfWindowsServices.Add("svc1");
            ListOfWindowsServices.Add("svc2");
            ListOfFWindowsServices.Add("svc3");
            var server = "https://mysite.whatever/";
            var apiKey = "API-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";   // I generated this via the Octopus UI         

            var endpoint = new OctopusServerEndpoint(server, apiKey);
            var repository = new OctopusRepository(endpoint);
            var project = repository.Projects.FindByName("Windows Services");

            // From here on is where I'm fuzzy:
            //
            var procesSteps = GetProcessSteps(project);
            var processStepToClone = GetProcesStepByName(processSteps, "SomeProcessStep");
            foreach (string svcName in ListofSvcNames)
            {
                processStepToClone.StepName = svcName;
                processStepToClone.PackageID = svcName;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

I've made a little more progress.  I'm now able to access the Steps in the Process, and add a Step.  However, when my code calls repository.DeploymentProcesses.Modify, I get this exception:

- Please provide a value for the package ID.
- Please select the feed that this package will be downloaded from.
- Please select one or more roles that 'svc1' step will apply to.

Here's my latest code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> ListOfFexWindowsServices = new List<string>();
        ListOfFexWindowsServices.Add("svc2");
        ListOfFexWindowsServices.Add("svc3");
        ListOfFexWindowsServices.Add("svc4");
        string server = "https://mysite.stuff/";
        string apiKey = "API-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";   // I generated this via the Octopus UI         

        OctopusServerEndpoint endpoint = new OctopusServerEndpoint(server, apiKey);
        OctopusRepository repository = new OctopusRepository(endpoint);
        ProjectResource projectResource = repository.Projects.FindByName("MyProject");
        DeploymentProcessResource deploymentProcess = repository.DeploymentProcesses.Get(projectResource.DeploymentProcessId);

        var projectSteps = deploymentProcess.Steps;
        DeploymentStepResource stepToClone = new DeploymentStepResource();
        foreach (DeploymentStepResource step in projectSteps)
        {
            if (step.Name == "svc1")
            {
                stepToClone = step;
                break;
            }
        }

        foreach (string serviceName in ListOfFexWindowsServices)
        {
            DeploymentStepResource newStep = new DeploymentStepResource();
            PopulateNewStep(newStep, stepToClone, serviceName);
            deploymentProcess.Steps.Add(newStep);
            repository.DeploymentProcesses.Modify(deploymentProcess);
        }
    }

    static void PopulateNewStep(DeploymentStepResource newStep, DeploymentStepResource stepToClone, string serviceName)
    {
        newStep.Name = serviceName;
        newStep.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        newStep.StartTrigger = stepToClone.StartTrigger;
        newStep.Condition = stepToClone.Condition;
        DeploymentActionResource action = new DeploymentActionResource
        {
            Name = newStep.Name,
            ActionType = "Octopus.TentaclePackage",
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        };

        PopulateActionProperties(action);
        newStep.Actions.Add(action);
        // ISSUE:  Anything else to do (eg, any other things from stepToClone to copy, or other stuff to create)?
        newStep.PackageRequirement = stepToClone.PackageRequirement;

    }

    static void PopulateActionProperties(DeploymentActionResource action)
    {
        action.Properties.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, PropertyValueResource>("Octopus.Action.WindowsService.CustomAccountPassword", "#{WindowsService.Password}"));

        // TODO:  Repeat this sort of thing for each Action Property you see in stepToClone.
    }
```

Comment: There are sample `Octopus.Client` scripts in this [repo](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctopusDeploy-Api)

Comment: Would the octo.exe command line tool combination of [export](https://octopus.com/docs/api-and-integration/octo.exe-command-line/export) and [import](https://octopus.com/docs/api-and-integration/octo.exe-command-line/import) not help?

Answer (score 0):

```
void Main()
{
    var sourceProjectName = "<source project name>";
    var targetProjectName = "<target project name>";
    var stepToCopyName = "<step name to copy>";

    var repo = GetOctopusRepository();
    var sourceProject = repo.Projects.FindByName(sourceProjectName);
    var targetProject = repo.Projects.FindByName(targetProjectName);

    if (sourceProject != null && targetProject != null)
    {
        var sourceDeploymentProcess = repo.DeploymentProcesses.Get(sourceProject.DeploymentProcessId);
        var targetDeploymentProcess = repo.DeploymentProcesses.Get(targetProject.DeploymentProcessId);

        if (sourceDeploymentProcess != null && targetDeploymentProcess != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Start copy from project '{sourceProjectName}' to project '{targetProjectName}'");

            CopyStepToTarget(sourceDeploymentProcess, targetDeploymentProcess, stepToCopyName);

            // Update or add the target deployment process
            repo.DeploymentProcesses.Modify(targetDeploymentProcess);

            Console.WriteLine($"End copy from project '{sourceProjectName}' to project '{targetProjectName}'");
        }
    }
}

private OctopusRepository GetOctopusRepository()
{
    var octopusServer = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OCTOPUS_CLI_SERVER");
    var octopusApiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OCTOPUS_CLI_API_KEY");
    var endPoint = new OctopusServerEndpoint(octopusServer, octopusApiKey);

    return new OctopusRepository(endPoint);
}

private void CopyStepToTarget(DeploymentProcessResource sourceProcess, DeploymentProcessResource targetProcess, string sourceStepName, bool includeChannels = false, bool includeEnvironments = false)
{
    var sourceStep = sourceProcess.FindStep(sourceStepName);

    if (sourceStep == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{sourceStepName} not found in {sourceProcess.ProjectId}");
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"-> copy step '{sourceStep.Name}'");

    var stepToAdd = targetProcess.AddOrUpdateStep(sourceStep.Name);
    stepToAdd.RequirePackagesToBeAcquired(sourceStep.RequiresPackagesToBeAcquired);
    stepToAdd.WithCondition(sourceStep.Condition);
    stepToAdd.WithStartTrigger(sourceStep.StartTrigger);

    foreach (var property in sourceStep.Properties)
    {
        if (stepToAdd.Properties.ContainsKey(property.Key))
        {
            stepToAdd.Properties[property.Key] = property.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            stepToAdd.Properties.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
        }
    }

    foreach (var sourceAction in sourceStep.Actions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"-> copy action '{sourceAction.Name}'");

        var targetAction = stepToAdd.AddOrUpdateAction(sourceAction.Name);
        targetAction.ActionType = sourceAction.ActionType;
        targetAction.IsDisabled = sourceAction.IsDisabled;

        if (includeChannels)
        {
            foreach (var sourceChannel in sourceAction.Channels)
            {
                targetAction.Channels.Add(sourceChannel);
            }
        }

        if (includeEnvironments)
        {
            foreach (var sourceEnvironment in sourceAction.Environments)
            {
                targetAction.Environments.Add(sourceEnvironment);
            }
        }

        foreach (var actionProperty in sourceAction.Properties)
        {
            if (targetAction.Properties.ContainsKey(actionProperty.Key))
            {
                targetAction.Properties[actionProperty.Key] = actionProperty.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                targetAction.Properties.Add(actionProperty.Key, actionProperty.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> The above code sample is available in the [Octopus Client Api Samples](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctopusDeploy-Api/tree/master/Octopus.Client)